# Why the git commands are taking so long to execute?

Tags: git

Suddenly all git commands started to get too long to run. Simple commands like `git log, git status, git add` are taking up to one minute to execute.

I tried using the `git gc` but unfortunately I'm having this problem in all the repositories, even at the ones that I just started and barely have 10 commits (in this one - https://github.com/paulodelia/bapi - takes like 30 seconds to run a `git log` ).

I tried to reinstall git, but nothing changed. And I can't understand why because 3 days ago I could do a `git log` in a repository with a lot of commits and get the output instantly.

I would much appreciate if someone can help me with this, I'm losing a lot of time just waiting for the `git status` and `git add`.

By the way, I'm using windows. And usually, I have my repositories in the HD, but to test I copied a project to the SSD, to see if the SSD speed could help me, and unfortunately get the same results.

Comment: Enterprise application blocklisting? Anti-virus scanner configuration? Those are the usual culprits... And Git spawns MANY processes.

Comment: OMG, when you said "Enterprise" I disconnected from the VPN from my job and now it's really fast again. Thank you!!! This made my day, I was getting so frustrated with this.
Now I just can't understand why would get slow just by connecting to the VPN. That's so strange.

Comment: You could try using a network sniffer such as Wireshark, or even plain old "Process Explorer" to see where your system is trying to connect. I bet that it is trying to download the "Certificate Revokation Lists" of the certificates used to sign Git.exe. In my system it would be http://crl.certum.pl/ca.crl.

Answer (score 1):

After I disconnected from my job's VPN the problem was solved. I don't understand why this happens but after testing A LOT I can say with confidence that being connected to the VPN was causing the slowness.

And thinking back, the problem began on the day I started using the VPN. For me, it's a really strange problem but now it's solved.

Thank you `jessehouwing`, your comment helped me a lot.

Comment: You're welcome. These kinds of weird behaviors van be the most frustrating ever.